# WhatsApp Web Messages

Tags: whatsapp

Can I open the same WhatsApp from a phone on several computers at once? So that people can answer or send several messages at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No. If you open several WhatsApp Web sessions you will see this massage:

*WhatsApp is open in another computer or browser.
 Click "Use Here" to use WhatsApp in this window.*

[image]